# From where can I import the webapp2 response class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

My IDE PyCharm is complaining about the variable `response` in the following code and it has been marked red as unresolved reference even though the code is working. I'd like to fix it and I suppose the problem is that I don't import the response class. How can I do it? Where should it be imported from?

```
class Base2Handler(BaseRequestHandler):
    @webapp2.cached_property
    def jinja2(self):
        return jinja2.get_jinja2(app=self.app)

    facebook = None
    #user = None
    csrf_protect = True

    def render_template(self, file, template_args):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates',
                            file)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_args))

    def render_json(self, response):
        self.response.write("%s(%s);" % (self.request.GET['callback'],
                                         json.dumps(response)))

    def dispatch(self):

        # Get a session store for this request.
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
        if self.request.host.find('.br') > 0:  # for a Brazilian domain that uses Portuguese
            i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('pt-br')
        else:
            lang_code = self.session.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', None)
            if not lang_code:
                lang_code = os.environ.get('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE')
            if lang_code:
                i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code)
            lang_code_get = self.request.get('hl', None)
            if lang_code_get:
                self.session['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = lang_code_get
                i18n.get_i18n().set_locale(lang_code_get)
        try:
            # Dispatch the request.
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            # Save all sessions.
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.
        return self.session_store.get_session()

    @property
    def current_email(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_current_email'):
            self._current_email = None
            host = self.request.host
            if host.find('.br') > 0:
                email = 'Montao.com.br <info@montao.com.br>'
            else:
                email = 'Kool Business <info@koolbusiness.com>'

            self._current_email = email
        return self._current_email

    @property
    def current_host(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_current_host'):
            self._current_host = self.request.host
        return self._current_host

    @property
    def current_logo(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_current_logo'):
            self._current_logo = self.request.host.replace('www', '')
        return self._current_logo

    def initialize(self, request, response):
        """General initialization for every request"""
        super(Base2Handler, self).initialize(request, response)
        try:
            self.init_csrf()
            self.response.headers['P3P'] = 'CP=HONK'  # iframe cookies in IE
            # Decide the language
            if self.request.host.find('montao.com.br') > 0:
                i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('pt-br')
            elif self.request.host.find('gralumo.com') > 0:
                i18n.get_i18n().set_locale('es-ar')
        except Exception, ex:
            self.log_exception(ex)
            raise

    def handle_exception(self, ex, debug_mode):
        """Invoked for unhandled exceptions by webapp"""
        self.log_exception(ex)
        self.render('error', trace=traceback.format_exc(),
                    debug_mode=debug_mode)

    def log_exception(self, ex):
        """Internal logging handler to reduce some App Engine noise in errors"""
        msg = (str(ex) or ex.__class__.__name__) + ': \n' \
              + traceback.format_exc()
        if isinstance(ex, urlfetch.DownloadError) or isinstance(ex,
                                                                CsrfException) or isinstance(ex,
                                                                                             taskqueue.TransientError):
            logging.warn(msg)
        else:
            logging.error(msg)

    def set_cookie(
            self,
            name,
            value,
            expires=None,
            ):

        if value is None:
            value = 'deleted'
            expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=-50000)
        jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
        jar[name] = value
        jar[name]['path'] = '/'
        if expires:
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.timedelta):
                expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
                expires = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
            jar[name]['expires'] = expires
        self.response.headers.add_header(*jar.output().split(': ', 1))

    def set_webapp2_cookie(
            self,
            name,
            value,
            expires=None,
            ):

        if value is None:
            self.response.delete_cookie(name)
        if expires:
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.timedelta):
                expires = datetime.datetime.now() + expires
            if isinstance(expires, datetime.datetime):
                expires = expires.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
        response.set_cookie(
            name,
            value,
            max_age=expires,
            path='/',
            domain=self.request.host.replace('www', ''),
            secure=True,
            )

    def render_jinja(self, name,
                     **data):  # if we put two stars in front of the dictionary when calling the function, the dictionary is transformed into named arguments

        logo_url = '/_/img/kool_business.png'
        if self.request.host.find('.br') > 0:
            logo_url = '/_/img/montao_small.gif'

        if not data:
            data = {}

        data['logged_in_user'] = self.current_user
        data['message'] = self.get_message()
        data['csrf_token'] = self.csrf_token
        data['user'] = self.current_user  #users.get_current_user()
        #user = users.get_current_user()
        host = self.request.host
        data['host'] = host
        data['logo'] = host.replace('www.', '').capitalize()
        data['user_url'] = \
            (users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else users.create_login_url(
                self.request.uri))
        data['request'] = self.request
        data['logo_url'] = logo_url
        data['admin'] = users.is_current_user_admin()
        self.response.write(self.jinja2.render_template(name + '.html',
                                                        **data))

    def render(self, name, **data):

        logo = 'Koolbusiness.com'
        logo_url = '/_/img/kool_business.png'
        domain = 'koolbusiness'
        if not data:
            data = {}
        data['message'] = self.get_message()
        data['csrf_token'] = self.csrf_token
        data['user'] = users.get_current_user()
        data['login_url'] = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
        host = self.request.host
        data['host'] = host
        if host.find('.br') > 0:
            logo_url = '/_/img/montao_small.gif'

        data['logo'] = logo
        data['logo_url'] = logo_url
        data['user_url'] = \
            (users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri) if users.get_current_user() else users.create_login_url(
                self.request.uri))
        data['admin'] = users.is_current_user_admin()

        self.response.out.write(template.render(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                                             'templates', name + '.html'), data))

    def init_csrf(self):
        """Issue and handle CSRF token as necessary"""

        self.csrf_token = self.request.cookies.get('c')
        if not self.csrf_token:
            self.csrf_token = str(uuid4())[:8]
            self.set_cookie('c', self.csrf_token)

            # if self.request.method == 'POST' and self.csrf_protect \
            #    and self.csrf_token != self.request.get('_csrf_token'):
            #    raise CsrfException('Missing or invalid CSRF token.')

    def set_message(self, **obj):
        """Simple message support"""
        self.set_cookie('m',
                        (base64.b64encode(json.dumps(obj)) if obj else None))

    def get_message(self):
        """Get and clear the current message"""
        message = self.request.cookies.get('m')
        if message:
            self.set_message()  # clear the current cookie
            return json.loads(base64.b64decode(message))
```

Comment: from where you installed it ?

Comment: You should show your imports.

Comment: That's a large chunk of code you pasted in. Can you be more specific about where in your code you see the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red notch(es) on the right side scrollbar can get you close by and you should see the offending code underlined with red. With the editor cursor on the underlined text <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> gives you details.

Better yet: Code -> Inspect Code should show exactly which line the complaint is about.

Missing a 'self.' in set_webapp2_cookie() maybe?

```
    response.set_cookie(
```